# Bug Checking Setters and Getters

Tags: java, debugging, setter, getter

Java is telling me that my setter function does not exist... why?
When I set the author later in my code I got the error message but my setter for Titles which is basically in the same format returns no error.

```
class Author {
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    int birth_year;
    int death_year;
    Author writer;

    Author () {}

    Author(String LastName, String FirstName) {
        first_name= FirstName;
        last_name = LastName;
    }

    Author getAuthor() {
        return writer;
    }
    void setAuthor(Author Writer) {
        Writer = writer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exception please?

Comment: This naming convention is confusing.

Comment: Capitalizing argument names is generally considered bad style in Java.

Comment: Good naming convention goes a long way.  Sometimes naming convention is critiqued just for the sake of critiquing naming convention.  But this is a case where poor naming options leads to lots of confusion...

Comment: The exception is: "The function setAuthor( project.Author) does not exist.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm just setting it up how my TA for the class wants it. I didn't choose the names or capitalization.

Comment: Then kindly explain your TA that he should teach universally accepted naming conventions instead of teaching his own, non-standard ones. Point him to this piece of documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: I definitely will. Thought it was odd structure when he told me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm pretty sure that Java isn't telling that. You should always paste the exact error message.

That said, your setter initializes the argument of the setter with the value of the field, instead of initializing the field with the value of the argument.

It should be:

```
void setAuthor (Author Writer) {
    this.writer = Writer;
}
```

You should respect the Java naming conventions, and be consistent in your naming. Variables start with a lowercase letter. They naver contain an underscore and are camelCased: `firstName`, `lastName`, etc. And using `this.xxx = xxx` in a systematic way in setters allow avoiding those kinds of bug.

It also seems like you have a design problem. Why would an author have an author? A book should have an author. But an author shouldn't have an author.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, don't know why I had it in the author class. I just moved it to my book class and it's working perfectly. I was getting the error from processing. Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
  void setAuthor (Author Writer) {
    Writer = writer;
  }
```

This doesn't set the `writer` field to the value of the `Writer` argument. This sets the `Writer` argument to the value of the `writer` field. As it stands, it's useless. You want

```
  void setAuthor (Author Writer) {
    writer = Writer;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void setAuthor (Author Writer) {
    Writer = writer;
  }
```

`Writer = writer;` sets the value in the LOCAL variable `Writer` FROM instance variable `writer`

Answer (score 0):

make them public like that

```
public class Author {
      String first_name;
      String last_name;
      int birth_year;
      int death_year;
      Author writer;
      Author () {
      }
      Author(String LastName, String FirstName) {
        first_name= FirstName;
        last_name = LastName;
      }
      public Author getAuthor() {
        return this.writer;
      }
      public void setAuthor (Author Writer) {
        this.writer = Writer;
      }
    }
```